# Is there a way to pass javascript variables in url?

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a way to make the below script pass the javascript values to the url of the href link?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function geoPreview(lat,long) {
var elemA = document.getElementById("lat").value;
var elemB = document.getElementById("long").value;

window.location.href = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=elemA&lon=elemB&setLatLon=Set";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
 window.location.href = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat="+elemA+"&lon="+elemB+"&setLatLon=Set";
```

To put a variable in a string enclose the variable in quotes and addition signs like this:

```
var myname = "BOB";
var mystring = "Hi there "+myname+"!";
```

Just remember that one rule!

Comment: Don't stick arbitrary strings directly into a URL. You need to encode them properly with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: This is a bad practice, do not perform this action without proper sanitisation.

Comment: Would be nice to see the correct way to do that if this is retained to be bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean include javascript variable values in the query string of the URL?

Yes:

```
 window.location.href = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat="+var1+"&lon="+var2+"&setLatLon="+varEtc;
```

Comment: Don't stick arbitrary strings directly into a URL. You need to encode them properly with `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

With either **string concatenation** or **string interpolation** (via **template literals**).

Here with JavaScript template literal:

```js
function geoPreview() {
    var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
    var long = document.getElementById("long").value;

    window.location.href = `http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&setLatLon=Set`;
}
```

Both parameters are unused and can be removed.

## Remarks

### String Concatenation

Join strings with the `+` operator:

```js
window.location.href = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=" + elemA + "&lon=" + elemB + "&setLatLon=Set";
```

### String Interpolation

For more concise code, use JavaScript **template literals** to replace expressions with their string representations.
Template literals are enclosed by ``` `` ``` and placeholders surrounded with `${}`:

```js
window.location.href = `http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=${elemA}&lon=${elemB}&setLatLon=Set`;
```

*Template literals are available since ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).*

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to set your `variable` in url

```
var roomname = '2nxjoinroomnot9480';
window.location.replace("/login?roomid=" + roomname);
```

In and in the give page `URL` you can get `variable` like this

```
const roomId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('roomid');
console.log(roomId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=\''+elemA+'\'&lon=\''+elemB+'\'&setLatLon=Set";
```