# How do it have a radio button pass data hidden from url?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, hidden-field

Here is the thing, I have to show a proof of concept, in which I:

- Pass data from page to page using the url section and displaying the data passed in another page.
- Pass data from page to page **NOT** using the url section and displaying the data passed in another page.

Meaning I want one of the radio button to behave as: input type="hidden",
But I do not know how to do that, to clarify there is a code snipped below. Any help is appreciated. To clarify, it should not show the value of the radio button in the query string.

```html
<form method="POST" action="Confirm.jsp">


  <p>
    Choose:
    <input type="radio" checked name="QuizType" value="Private">Private
    <input type="radio" name="QuizType" value="Public">Public
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form:

```
<form id="frm1">
<p>
  Choose:
  <input type="radio" checked name="QuizType" value="Private" id="radio">Private

  <input type="radio" name="QuizType" value="Public">Public

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</p>
</form>
```

Then you can get the selected value with JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('QuizType');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
     if (radios[i].checked) {

       // Store the value for the selected radio 
       // You can maybe redirected on another page and pass this variable
       $selectedRadio = radios[i].value

       alert($selectedRadio);
       break;
     }
   }
}
```

Check this **[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwoXRx)**.

If you want to pass variables to the url then you should try:

```
window.location.href+'/'+$selectedRadio;
```

**Resources:**
[Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript), [Is there a way to pass javascript variables in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863986/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variables-in-url), [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page)

Comment: Thank you for that, ultimately though I decided that for my needs I would just create two forms, one with POST method and one without it. That way the "public" one would show the data in the query string and the private one would not.