# Put variable into url

Tags: javascript

A have an image address of my IP cam:

```
snapshot.cgi?user=#USERNAME&pwd=#PASSWORD
```

I need to put those two variables below in place #USERNAME and #PASSWORD:

```
var user = "test";
var pass = "test";
```

Finish result must be:

```
snapshot.cgi?user=test&pwd=test
```

I know there is a way to do that but i don't know how. The address of image need to stay exactly like it is as I am getting this from external source.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863986/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variables-in-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.replace` function:

```
var originalLink = "snapshot.cgi?user=#USERNAME&pwd=#PASSWORD",
    user = "test",
    pass = "test";

var newLink = originalLink.replace("#USERNAME", user).replace("#PASSWORD", pass);
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

To create a variable with that url, the quick code would be:

```
var user = "test";
var pass = "test";
var url = "snapshot.cgi?user="+user+"&pwd="+pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your image url address saved as a string url? If so, then you can do the following...

```
var user = "test";
var pass = "test";
var url = "snapshot.cgi?user=#" + user + "&pwd=#" + pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the replace method of the string.

```
function getNewUrl (userName, password) {

        return "snapshot.cgi?user=#USERNAME&pwd=#PASSWORD"
                .replace("#USERNAME", userName)
                .replace("#PASSWORD", password);
    }
```

Comment: what if the values are changed for username and password. you should pass in variables.