# How to read iframe src of chrome extension from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**I want to pass a value through URL of iframe to my node server from my chrome extension. I want to get the src on server**

var webAppURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";

var iframe = document.getElementById("token"); // creating iframe and define id

```
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = "token";
        iframe.src = webAppURL ;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `var webAppURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000?data=yourData"`. Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863986/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variables-in-url

Comment: And in the server file you could read it like: 
`app.get('/', function(req, res) {
let data = req.query.data;
...`