# Accessing and storing a JS Variable In PHP Database stores tag

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I accessed and stored JS Value like the following example.

````
<script>
   var res = "success";
</script>
<?php
   $value = "<script>document.writeln(res);</script>";
   echo $value;           // It works.
   addTodb($value);      //Stores script tag instead of value;
?>```
Accessing actual value and then to output it works. But when I store the value in database, it stores "<script>document.writeln(res);</script>" as a plain text instead of the value.
I have even tried to use sessions but still the same.
````

Comment: You are not storing the script tag. You are storing the string.

Comment: PHP will not magically evaluate your javascript. If you want to use in PHP a variable that's evaluated with JS, you need to pass it to PHP in a query string or post data.

Comment: Thank You Markus AO. 
I have passed the variable values in a query string and it worked. Here is the related question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863986/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variables-in-url